# insert output from mysql query into html table one after another

Tags: php, html, mysql

heloo, i want to serarch particular row from mysql database and same should be displayed on html table. I have tried the below code but it only gives the single row which is result of current query, previous row get overwritten. I am fetching a row for particular id,next time when i give another id,another row should be fetched and it should be added to the table next to previous one..

```
     <html>
    <body>
    <form action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>" method="POST">
    <tr>
    ProductID: <input type="number" name="ProductID">
    <input type="submit" value ="Go"> 
   </form>
   </tr>
 </body>
 </html>


 <?php

   $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","m70830807","Inventory");
// Check connection
if (!$con)
 {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
  mysqli_select_db("Inventory",$con);
 $ID=$_POST['ProductID'];
 //echo $ID;
 $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT ProductID, ProductName, UnitPrice FROm  Products_Sold where ProductID =" .$ID);

echo"<table border = '1'>
<tr>
<th>ProductID</th>
<th>ProductName</th>
<th>UnitPrice</th>
</tr> ";
//$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
 //$c1= $row['ProductID'];
 //$c2=$row['ProductName'];
  //$c3=$row['UnitPrice'];
  //echo $c1; 
 //echo $c2;
 //echo $c3;

    //$ins= mysqli_query($con,"insert into Temp (ProductID,ProductName,UnitPrice) values ('%d','%s','%f')", $c1,$c2,$c3);

   //$fetch=mysqli_query($con,"select ProductId,ProductName,UnitPrice from  Temp");
      while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
     { echo "<tr>";
     echo "<td>". $row['ProductID'] . "</td>";
     echo  "<td>" . $row['ProductName'] ." </td>";
     echo   "<td>" . $row['UnitPrice'] . "</td>";
     echo "</tr> ";

     }
     echo "</table>";

      mysqli_close($con);


      ?>
```

Comment: With PhP you cannot do what you want. You need to give a list of id to be searched or you need to think about a Ajax call to another page to add it to your table without deleting other rows.

Comment: php works on server side, so it will overwrite your record on each request. you can append the next row by using jquery and ajax.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do this within a user session (one user has one list. Another got different) so you need to use [session](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php)

In your example -

```
<?php
session_start();
   $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","m70830807","Inventory");
// Check connection
if (!$con)
 {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
  mysqli_select_db("Inventory",$con);
 $ID=$_POST['ProductID'];
 $_SESSION['ids'][mysql_escape_string($ID)] = array();
 //echo $ID;
 $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT ProductID, ProductName, UnitPrice FROm  Products_Sold where ProductID IN (\"" . implode('","', usort(array_keys( $_SESSION['ids']))). '");');
echo"<table border = '1'>
<tr>
    <th>
        ProductID
    </th>
    <th>
        ProductName
    </th>
    <th>
        UnitPrice
    </th>
</tr>
 "; 
while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { echo "
<tr>
    "; echo "
    <td>
        ". $row['ProductID'] . "
    </td>
    "; echo "
    <td>
        " . $row['ProductName'] ."
    </td>
    "; echo "
    <td>
        " . $row['UnitPrice'] . "
    </td>
    "; echo "
</tr>
 "; } echo "
</table>
";
      mysqli_close($con);
      ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ajax and jquery to do this.

send request via ajax and get response as your row. Manipulate the table using jquery to append in the existing set of records